# How do I get an object's value stored in localStorage?

Tags: angular, local-storage

I have stored an object with multiple properties in localStorage. It does not contain a single value like a string or a number. The name of the localStorage key is `UserData` and its value is the following object:

```
{
    key: "1287C31D714BE16FBD44D093E4173CFF"
    logTime: "20191013190439"
    operatorDni: "46653980"    
}
```

I need to retrieve the value of the object property `operatorDni` in order to perform some actions in my code. I have tried to retrieve it using this line of code:

```
operatorDni: string;

this.operatorDni= localStorage.getItem('UserData.operatorDni');
```

But I get `null`.

How can I get a property of an object in `localStorage` with the key? What am I doing wrong?

Thank you very much.

Comment: If you view your localStorage, does the key have the correct value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Storing Objects in HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2010892/storing-objects-in-html5-localstorage)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `JSON.parse` like

```
var userData= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('UserData'))
this.operatorDni=userData.operatorDni;
```

Also save it like

```
localStorage.setItem('UserData',JSON.stringify(yourObject))
```